# Installed Ubuntu on top of XP and can't boot XP

Tags: dual-boot

I had Windows XP installed without partitioned hard drive, and partitioned and installed Ubuntu with the Ubuntu live cd. There is no menu at startup for which operating system; it just boots up Ubuntu. Suggestions?

Comment: Can you go to System->Administration->Disk Utility, click on your hard disk in the left hand column then add a screenshot of this to your answer so that we can see what partitions you have?

Comment: @user8911: What method of partitioning did you select? I'm afraid that Windows XP partition has been over-written/corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it didn't pick up XP during the installation. In Ubuntu, click `Applications > Accessories > Terminal` and then type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will update the GRUB menu. If it says something like:

```
Found Windows XP (loader) on /dev/sda1
```

then you should be able to choose between XP and Ubuntu during your next boot.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I already tried that, though.

Comment: Please add what you've already tried to the answer.